# How to properly Web Scrape YouTube with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and I'm trying to web **scrape** youtube for video titles on a search query like this `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nodejs+tutorial` and I'm trying to achieve this using node.js

and so far my code looks like this:

```
const express= require('express');
const ejs =require('ejs');
const got = require('got');

async function scrape(url){
    try {
        const response = await got(url);
        return response.body;
    } 
    catch (error) {
        return error.response.body;
    }
}

const app=express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
     res.render('./index/index.ejs');
});

app.post('/',async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    var scrape_html= await scrape(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${req.body.url}`);
    res.json({'html':scrape_html});
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server now listening...');
});
```

but the `scrape_html` does not look anything like the actual html when you actually visit the site in a browser, why is that so? how do I get the actual html of the web page? does it have something to do with cookies?

Comment: how about using their API? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: @germanio I thought about using an API but it's a bit limiting, the project I'm working on is a bit hard to explain but it would be really helpful if I could get the entire html code when someone visits the website

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you something like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/). Here is the code ([this is how it works](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/YouTube-scrape-with-NodeJS-Puppeteer?v=1)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const queryup = "nodejs+tutorial";
const query = encodeURI(queryup);

async function YTSearch(searchQuery) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${searchQuery}`
  );
  await page.waitForSelector("div#contents");
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);

  const titles = await page.evaluate(function () {
    return Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll("ytd-video-renderer a#video-title")
    ).map((el) => ({
      title: el.getAttribute("title"),
      link: "https://www.youtube.com" + el.getAttribute("href"),
    }));
  });

  await browser.close();
  console.log(titles);
}

YTSearch(query);
```